# Converting a list of numbers into q-ary representation in Sage

Tags: python, binary, sage

```
"(n,p^n)"
n=2
p=3
p.is_prime()
n in ZZ
list1=list(IntegerRange(0,(p^n)-1))
V1=vector(GF(3),list1)
print V1
list1.digits(base=p,padto=n)
```

Trying to get output:

```
[(0, 0),(0, 1),(0, 2),(1, 0),(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 0),(2, 1),(2, 2)]
```

I cannot figure out how to use a list and convert it into a form where I can use the .digits function

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from trying to apply the `digits` method
to the list rather than to each elements in the list.

Having defined

```
sage: n = 2
sage: p = 3
```

and, recalling that `range(a, b)` and `IntegerRange(a, b)` both
include `a` but exclude `b`,

```
sage: list1 = list(IntegerRange(0, p^n))
```

one can then observe `list1`

```
sage: list1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and apply the `digits` method to elements of `list1`

```
sage: [ZZ(x).digits(base=p, padto=n) for x in list1]
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

possibly then reversing these digits:

```
sage: [ZZ(x).digits(base=p, padto=n)[::-1] for x in list1]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```